# Multiple Choices error page in 1and1

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have done my project using laravel. I want to upload my project on 1and1. I set my directory structure on 1and1 is as '/directory' which contains index.html file which links to the other page in /directory/EngageV1/public/auth/login. but when I visits this page I am getting the error page as,

> Multiple Choices
>   The document name you requested (/index.php) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.
>   Available documents:
>   /index.html (common basename)
>   Please consider informing the owner of the referring page about the broken link.

My `.htaccess` file looks like,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

If enter url as /directory/EngageV1/public/ then it shows me the welcome page which I have set in routes.php file for route as '/'. Only this page works fine,I don't know what to do, Please give any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is is an very old topic, but it took us some time today to find out what's going wrong on an old 1and1 (now Ionos) server. Turned out, the "multiple choices" page doesn't com from `Option +MultiViews` / `mod_negotiation`, but from a module called `mod_speling` that's running there by default. You can disable it in the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
    CheckSpelling off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace default contents in your `.htaccess` file under your the `public`
folder with the following.

```
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If you still have problems look at this [tutorial](http://carlorodriguez.github.io/blog/2016/01/29/deploy-laravel-webapp-to-1and1/) about how to deploy a Laravel webapp to 1and1