# Leaflet and shifted tiles when loading from a server and not local

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, maps

That's a first to me, asking a question because I can't find an answer.

My problem is strange. I made a map with my own tile servers.
Local everything is fine.
But after uploading the tiles to a server strange things happen.

[image: Screenshot of Shifted tiles]

The tiles are loaded, but then are duplicated and shifted, but not all, Bahn 5 is fine.

See yourself: http://s521441731.online.de/map/leaflet.html#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from my web browser's network tab, it seems that some of the tile requests are being redirected, because the web server is thinking that the user made a typo in the URL:

[image: Screenshot of network tab in developer's tools]

In there, when my browser is requesting the `/16/34058/43768.png` image, the webserver is issuing a 301 HTTP response code, which means "the thing you're looking for is at a different place", and then tells my browser to look at `/16/34059/43768.png` instead.

Why do I think that this is the web server trying to be too clever for its own good? Because for some other tile requests, it actually replies with:

[image: Screenshot of network tab in developer's tools]

I suggest you contact your web server administrators, or else that you have a look at the configuration for the Apache webserver you're hosting your tiles at, particularly anything related to `mod_rewrite`. Be aware that, in some scenarios, you might be able to override the default Apache configuration by means of `.htaccess` files, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797731/multiple-choices-error-page-in-1and1). (Try setting the `RewriteEngine` options to off, maybe that'll just work)

If you are using Leaflet (or OpenLayers, or any other similar map display library), HTTP requests for non-existing tiles shall return a 404 HTTP code.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense

I only got 404, but this has to be it

I'll try it with a dirty workaround, adding empty tiles

Answer (score 0):

Yes black tiles removes the bug, there are black tiles everywhere except where there are real tiles

[black tiles + real tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMicr.png)

So it is a serversided problem, thank you very much